# How to plot multiple facets histogram with ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a dataframe structured like this

```
 Elem. Category. SEZa SEZb SEZc

  A.     ONE.     1.   3.   4
  B.     TWO.     4.   5.   6
```

i want to plot three histograms in three different facets (SEZa, SEZb, SEZc) with ggplot where the x values are the category values (ONE. e TWO.) and the y values are the number present in columns SEZa, SEZb, SEZc.

something like this:

[image]

how can I do? thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `df` is your data.frame, I would first convert from wide format to a long format:

```
new_df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = c("Elem", "Category"))
```

And then make the plot using `geom_col()` instead of `geom_histogram()` because it seems you've precomputed the y-values and wouldn't need ggplot to calculate these values for you.

```
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Category, y = value, fill = Elem)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is something like this :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(Category = c("One", "Two"),
                 SEZa = c(1, 4),
                 SEZb = c(3, 5),
                 SEZc = c(4, 6))

df <- melt(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Category, y = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable)) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ .)
```

My inspiration is :

http://felixfan.github.io/stacking-plots-same-x/